# Best practice for writing SQL queries in Jupyter

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am doing some analysis using Jupyter notebooks. I usually use `pandas.read_sql()` to write SQL queries in Jupyter. Recently I have written a relatively big query with multiple joins. Its about a 25 line query. What is the best practice when writing such queries in Jupyter? For example, writing a query like this is no biggie -

```
pd.read_sql('select cs1.CLIENT as ClientName from central cs1', db.connect_win())
```

It is easy to read and understand, but what about larger queries? I want them to have indention and such so they are easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
sql_query = """
  SELECT first_name, last_name
  FROM actor
  WHERE actor_id IN
  (
    SELECT actor_id
    FROM film_actor
    WHERE film_id IN
    (
      SELECT film_id
      FROM film
      WHERE title = 'ALTER VICTORY'
    )
  );
"""
actor = pd.read_sql(sql_query, db.connect_win())
```

There are some great VS Code Extensions, like `SQL Server (mssql)`. It will do automatic formatting for you. Sometimes I like using VS Code first, as a linting tool, and pasting the resulting query back into my Jupyter notebook.

Comment: this is quite a nice suggestion. Writing your queries like this will force you to break your bigger queries into small ones. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use CTEs:

```sql
WITH name AS (
  SELECT * FROM ...
), another AS (
  SELECT * FROM ...
)
SELECT * FROM ...
```

It is a lot more readable than nested sub-queries.

If you're using `pandas.read_sql`, you can do something like this:

```py
name = 'SELECT * FROM ...'
another = 'SELECT * FROM ...'
final_select = 'SELECT * FROM ...'

query = f"""
WITH name AS (
  {name}
), another AS (
  {another}
)
{final}
"""
```

Note that this will allow you to do any of these:

```py
pandas.read_sql(name, conn)
pandas.read_sql(another, conn)
pandas.read_sql(query, conn)
```

Which will be pretty handy for debugging parts of your query.

If you want to simplify this, you can use [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql), which allows you doing what I described before in a more straightforward way:

```sql
# cell 1
%%sql --save name --no-execute
SELECT * FROM ...

# cell 2
%%sql --save another --no-execute
SELECT * FROM ...

# cell 3
%%sql --with name --with another
SELECT * FROM ...
```

*Note:* `--no-execute` will skip executing the query, you can remove it if you want to see a preview of the results.

Under the hood, JupySQL will construct the CTE for you; here's a complete [example](https://jupysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compose.html).